# How does PHP know what the last database connection is when mysql_select_db() or mysql_query() is used without the optional database parameter?

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database', $conn);

?>
```

This works as expected, but how does PHP know what database connection to use when calling `mysql_select_db()` in the following example?

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');

?>
```

The PHP documentation states that "If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed." ([PHP: mysql_select_db()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php))

Where is the last connection stored or retrieved from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose a link to the last opened connection is kept somewhere in memory, to make things easier *(as we generally often use only one connection)*.

Quickly going through the sources of **`ext/mysql`** :

*(All line numbers are in `php_mysql.c` -- the version of the sources is a random snapshot of PHP 5.3.2-dev from a couple of weeks ago ; so, they might have changed a bit)*

- The user-space function called **`mysql_connect`** seems to correspond to the C-level function called **`php_mysql_do_connect`** *(line 922)*
- The **`php_mysql_do_connect`** function calls **`php_mysql_set_default_link`** *(line 832)*

  - To store the last opened connection
- There is also a function called **`php_mysql_get_default_link`** *(line 908)*
- That **`php_mysql_get_default_link`** function is called by **`mysql_select_db`**, when there is no link passed to it *(line 992)*

And **`php_mysql_set_default_link`** is calling this to store the `default_link` :

```
MySG(default_link) = id;
```

That `MySG` being a macro, defined like this *(in [`php_mysql_structs.h`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/mysql/php_mysql_structs.h?view=markup))* :

```
#ifdef ZTS
# define MySG(v) TSRMG(mysql_globals_id, zend_mysql_globals *, v)
#else
# define MySG(v) (mysql_globals.v)
#endif
```

Pretty much looks like a global variable to me ;-)

If you want, you can take a look at the sources yourself : **[`ext/mysql/php_mysql.c`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c?view=markup)** and **[`ext/mysql/php_mysql_structs.h`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/mysql/php_mysql_structs.h?view=markup)**.

*As I said, this has probably been modified a bit since the version in which I checked -- which means the line numbers might not match exactly ; but the functions names are easy anough to understand, so you should be able to track down what calls what and where :-)*

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; and in case of such a doubt, one of the great things about PHP is that it is open-source ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I wish this class will help you , i had already written it ............ sorry it needs testing

```
class connectionManager(){

protected $array = array(
"connection1" => "host3-username-password-database1" , 
"connection2" => "host2-username-password-database2" , 
"connection3" => "host1-username-password-database3" , 
)
protected $history = array();
public function __construct($connectionID = connection1){
 $this->savelastConnecton($connectionID);
     /*do you magic here to change the string above to desired format 
         sorry but i gatta go 
        btw i liked your question 
     */
      mysql_connect($host , $username , $password);
      mysql_select_db($database);
     return true ;
}
publich function getLastConnection( ){
    return end($this->history[$lastnumber]) ; 
}
private function saveLastConnection($connectionID){}
   $this->history[] = $connectionID ; 
    return true ;    

}
```